# How do I modify the join clause of a SQLAlchemy expression?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy expression equivalent to the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE (...)
```

I would like to modify the expression so that it is equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id 
WHERE (...)
```

Edit: To clarify, I am asking how to *modify* an already-existing expression object, not how to create a new expression object.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ORM version: T1 and T2 are mapped classes
q_old = session.query(T1, T2).filter(T1.id == T2.id).filter("mycondition")
print q_old
q_new = session.query(T1, T2).join(T2, T1.id == T2.id).filter("mycondition")
print q_new

# Core version: T1 and T2 are Table(...)
s_old = select("*").select_from(T1).where("mycondition")
print s_old
s_new = select("*").select_from(T1.join(T2, T1.c.id==T2.c.id)).where("mycondition")
print s_new
```

*I would advise against using `SELECT *` though and would suggest using `select([T1, T2])` instead.*

**Update:** In order to get from s_old to s_new you can try the following:

```
assert len(s_old._from_obj) == 1
T1inferred = s_old._from_obj[0]
s_upd = s_old.select_from(T1inferred.join(T2, T1inferred.c.id==T2.c.id))
print s_upd
```

Basically you try to get the `T1` from the given `s_old` so that you can construct a join, while `where` condition will be kept. *Note that the `SELECT *` will now return columns for both `T1` and `T2`.*

Comment: Hi van thanks for your answer, but please see my clarification - I need to modify an expression that already exists. In terms of your solution, I already have s_old and I do not have access to `mycondition` so I can't rebuild the expression from scratch.

Comment: I see, see the **Update** section of the answer.